# IndexTank how to handle permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, heroku, indextank

He**llo,
Given an Indextank index like so:
    class Threads < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :permissions
      include Tanker

```
  tankit 'rails_3_demo' do
    indexes :content
  end

  after_save :update_tank_indexes
  after_destroy :delete_tank_indexes

end
```

This index exists in my Thread model. Issue is threads have permissions. Currently if I allowed a user to search across the index they would be searching across all user's threads.
What is the smart way to handle permissions so I user can only search across threads the user has permissions to access.
Thanks**

**SCHEMA:**

```
USER (id)
PROJECT (id)
PERMISSION (user_id, project_id)
Thread (project_id)
```

As long as a user has a permission record for a project they can view all of that project's threads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is to also index permissions and have append "AND permissions:[value]" to your queries, where value are the permissions that match the user. That way a user would only see the results that have the right permissions.

In order to give you more details I'd need to know your permission scheme, but for example your permissions variable that you index could be a string with words such as "root joe bob jim" for a thread that only those users can access.

Comment: Diego, sounds fascinating though I'm not sure I understand how to implement it. Are you thinking to create a whole new index in addition or add the permissions as values to the current index?  In turns of my schema. I have updated the question above. thoughts?

Comment: You don't need another index. What I would do would be to have this: each thread would need a field with all ids of users who are allowed to see it. You want that field updated every time your permissions change, so that particular thread gets reindexed. In order for that field to be searchable, it needs to be a string where ids are separated by spaces. I have to be brief here, but send email to support at indextank com and we'll elaborate!